# Resource Controller with parameter on "store" action

Tags: php, rest, laravel-4

I am trying to implement a simple Photogallery (images, categories) using Laravel's [Resource Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).
An image is saved using the `store` action on my `ImageController`:

```
public function store()
{
...
}
```

I need to know the category of each image being uploaded, but the `store` action does not accept a parameter. Is there a way for the `store`  action to accept a parameter like this:

```
public function store($id)
{
...
}
```

or do I have to redeclare the route separately?
How can this be handled in the easiest way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can this be handled in the easiest way

Declare each route manually. It is much better than using the Resource controller *for this exact reason*.

[Here is a great blog post by Phil Sturgeon](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil) that talks about why you should just manually declare each route manually - it is overall a better process.

Comment: I don't understand why the `store` action does not accept a parameter... How am I supposed to store something in my DB if I can't even pass one parameter? Anyway, thank you, would you recommend to not use Restful Controllers at all?

Comment: You dont 'pass' the parameters. You "post" the parameters to the route, therefore you can give it as many variables as you want in your form.